# WCF extensibility point before Service Authorization

Tags: c#, wcf

Can anyone suggest which extensibility point i should use if i want to execute my code before the serviceAuthorization's CheckAccess method get called.

I tried with a custom Service behavior, that adds message inspectors, but they get called after the authorization...

many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try creating a custom ServiceAuthorization class and overriding the **CheckAccessCore**-method.

```
namespace Test
{
    public class ServiceAuthorization : ServiceAuthorizationManager
    {
        protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
        { // Do custom stuff here...
        }
     }
 }
```

Now configure your web.config to use this ServiceAuthorization class:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom" serviceAuthorizationManagerType="Test.ServiceAuthorization">
      </serviceAuthorization>
    </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: we already have a custom service authorization, my code has to go in before it hits that authorization ( or any other implementation of it)

Comment: iam sure it would work, but i would have to add it to every implementation of ServiceAuthorizations in our products or ask everyone to derive from my class